# Style.css in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I made a long break in programming. Almost half year now. I'm trying to include my style.css file in Laravel but it shows that it can't find it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Nauja pradžia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

    <h1 style="color: white">SVEIKAS</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me why it can't find it ? The file itself is in that directory.

Comment: A half year is not too long, I took 8 years long break from the web development and programming))

Comment: @feknaz you shouldn't delete questions after you got an answer, please appreciate answerer's effort and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `style.css` file into the `public/css` directory to make it work. Also, you can just use [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset) helper:

```
{{ asset('css/style.css') }}
```

Comment: Thank you... my bad... I didn't saw the created css directory in public.